# Why Django rest framework is restful?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm now writing my engineering thesis about REST and REST APIs, mostly focusing on Django REST framework as it was the framework we used in our engineering project. I just finished writing about the guidelines for API to be RESTful stated by Roy Fielding and I wanted to start section with implementations of REST architecture in Django REST Framework, but then I realized I don't really know why this framework is RESTful. I know what main paradigms are for API to be RESTful, but I don't know what specific parts of framwork inplements for example that our service is stateless or layered. Maybe someone can pinpoint what parts of django rest framework corresponds to specified guidelines for service to be RESTful ? If It's wrong site to ask this type of question then I'm sorry, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go through the points that make API a RESTful one

**1. Client-server architecture**
The very essence of the fact that you are developing a backend server, which is not part of your application UI is the point of this client-server architecture.
Every app you develop with Django Rest Framework (from now on DRF) is a backend API, which is separated from the client.

**2. Statelessness**
I cannot pin point the exact code line that shows why DRF is statelessness but its somewhere deep between Django and the WSGI/ASGI interface.
Somewhere in there you have some kind of code like this:

```
while True:
  request = io.listen_for_request()
  response = handle_request(request)
  return response
```

This "very pseudo" code is stateless! why? because we don't save or rely on any information between requests

**3. Cacheability**
This one is fairly simple, Django and DRF support caching [link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/caching/)

**4. Layered system**
This concept is kinda hard to correlate directly to DRF or Django. This is mainly done through the HTTP protocol.

**5. Code on demand (optional)**
`Servers can temporarily extend or customize the functionality of a client by transferring executable code: for example, compiled components such as Java applets, or client-side scripts such as JavaScript.`

Basically [Django Templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/templates/#:%7E:text=A%20Django%20template%20is%20a,interpreted%20by%20the%20template%20engine.&text=A%20template%20is%20rendered%20with,the%20context%2C%20and%20executes%20tags.). It allows you to send forms and pages as part of your endpoints.

**6. Uniform Interface**
Last but not least, the famous uniform interface. DRF helps you build your REST API interface by creating endpoints with the help of [Generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/templates/#:%7E:text=A%20Django%20template%20is%20a,interpreted%20by%20the%20template%20engine.&text=A%20template%20is%20rendered%20with,the%20context%2C%20and%20executes%20tags.). Those generic views help you create a full CRUD (create, read...) endpoint on a Django model with little to no effort. The created endpoint follows the Rest API interface of url structure for a resource.

Comment: Oh damn That's more then I wished for. Thanks !